# In a play, 10 actors (5 males and 5 females) are to be selected for 3 male roles and 3 female roles. In how many ways can this distribution happen?

Tags: combinatorics

To solve that, I'm thinking of the rule of product. For each role, 5 different actors could be selected, so I should consider (5 * 5 * 5) + (5 * 5 * 5) = 250 as the answer?

Comment: The problem in your solution  is that once an actor has been selected for role A, they can’t be selected for role B (I assume). So only 4 actors  are left for the remaining two roles.

Comment: Now I'm thinking the solution is (5*4*3) * (5*4*3) = 3600. For example, if we'd combine only the male roles, we'd have 5 * 4 * 3 ways of doing it, but, for every single male combination we have an equally number of female combinations, so it's (5 * 4 * 3)^2, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that’s it if the roles are different, for eg. Batman, Joker and Robin. But if roles are same, eg. three different Peter Parkers, then see @DanielCheca ‘s answer below.

Comment: No, they are distinct roles, like Ross, Chandler, Joey, Rachel, Monica and Phoebe. Thank you :)))

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the number of ways to select the male roles, given by the coefficient $\binom{5}{3}$, which is the same for the female. Now, by the rule of product, the number of ways to complete the task is $\binom{5}{3}\binom{5}{3}=100$.

Comment: This answer assumes the roles are indistinguishable, which is probably not intended.